# unexpected '<' when using php includes to reuse code

Tags: php

I'm trying to reuse code for a header of a site using php's "includes" statement.

In the index.php file (the home page) is:

```
<body>
<?php
include_once "includes/header.php";
?>
</body>
```

then header.php just has html, first few lines look like:

```
<?php

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container-fluid">
 .....
?>
```

And I'm getting an error message saying:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in header.php
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing, or maybe if there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then header.php just has html

No it doesn't.  It has PHP:

```
<?php // <---- Notice this

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    .....
?>
```

And it's syntactically invalid PHP, which is what the error is telling you.  If that file truly doesn't have any PHP code, remove the `<?php ?>` tags:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
.....
```

If it *does* have PHP code then you'll need to wrap only the PHP code in `<?php ?>` tags, not the HTML.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I'll accept the answer once time limit is over